# .NET: Updating a serialized object

Tags: .net, windows, serialization

I am dealing with a huge object in .NET.
It is a udt/struct.
Because creating this object is really time consuming (several hours), I create the object only once.
Then I serialize it, and I deserialize it at each program start. 
This way I can save many hours of processing time.

Now during the usage of my application, this object is changed (no items are added or removed, only variables are changed).

Serializing this object takes a bit of time (around 10 minutes).
If possible, I would like to avoid such a long saving time.

Is it possible to quickly update the serialized object, or is it only possible to serialize anew?

Comment: What kind of serialization do You use(XML/binary)?
I think decomposing Your giant object to smaller ones could be an alternative.

Comment: Another way to go may be serializing the object in a separate thread (e.g. in a background task). This way, you could start such a task after every change and maintain the latest serialized version. I agree with gkovacs90 that decomposing this huge struct into smaller scructs (which can be serialized separately) may be the better option...

Comment: Could You give more details about your object? What does it contain?